# MonoTouch crash logs

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to ensure that the release build of my MonoTouch app will produce crash logs that I can use, but I'm unable to get any crash logs from the device. Here are the steps I'm taking.

1. I put some code in my app that would force it to crash when the user touches the screen.
2. I did a release build and verified that the .dSYM folder is next to the .app folder.
3. I ran the app on my iPad and touched the screen to make it crash. The app exited instantly.
4. I did a Sync in iTunes.
5. I looked under Library\Logs\CrashReporter\MobileDevice[devicename] and [devicename].symbolicated, but there is nothing under there.

I've tried two methods of making the app crash. First way:

```
SomeObject x = null;
x.SomeFunction();
```

Second way:

```
unsafe {
    short *p = (short*)0;
    for ( int i=0; i < 1000000; i++ )
        p[i] = 0;
}
```

Both methods cause the app to exit instantly, but neither is producing a crash log.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you try looking at the crash log interface in Xcode Organizer, rather than relying on iTunes sync?

Comment: Yeah, these crashes don't show up in the Xcode Organizer either.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that unhandled managed exceptions do not generate a crash log.  Could you please file a bug at http://monotouch.net/Support so we can track and fix this issue?

In the mean time you could wrap your Main call in

```
try {
} catch {}
```

and log it somewhere and upload it to a web server you have or some such.

Comment: I've had my main wrapped in this for so long now, I'd forgotten I'd done this and assumed it was a feature of monotouch! :)

Comment: Is there a way to have it generate a crash log when I catch the exception? Also, can I dump the exception.ToString() output into the crash log somehow?

Comment: BTW I just submitted it as bug 673658.